# How to add dynamic tag in Azure Policy?

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I need to add the resource type as the tag value. Can someone help me to create this ?

So far I have this sample policy applied. I need to add the tag name resource_class with the resource type and it should get it from the type and I can split the name into Type name in value.

```
{
"mode": "Indexed",
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "field": "tags[division]",
        "exists": "false"
      },
      {
        "field": "tags[division_code]",
        "exists": "false"
      }
    
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "append",
    "details": [
      {
        "field": "tags[division]",
        "value": "[tolower(parameters('division'))]"
      },
      {
        "field": "tags[division_code]",
        "value": "[tolower(parameters('division_code'))]"
      }
    ]
  }
},
"parameters": {
  "division": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "division",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
    }
  },
  "division_code": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "division_code",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as '1234'"
    }
  }
  
}
```

}

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: I have upadated my question with policy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you are trying to add resource type as a tag value. if it's correct you can write like below

```
{
    "field": "tags[division]",
    "value": "[field('type')]"
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you. It is the same way MS has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation Currently, Not all resource types support tags. To determine if you can apply a tag to a resource type, see  [Tag support for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support).

You  can use  [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview)  Framework and there is [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#general) definition to reach your requirement.
Based  on the [doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies).
[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

. [Azure Policy pattern: tags| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-tags) .

.[Azure Poilicy Sample| MS DOC.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/#deploy-with-azure-powershell)